# All rows between to column dates

Tags: database, analysis

I have one table, call it **X** which contains the columns **ID** and **CreatedDate** and another table **Y** that contains **ID, CreatedDate** and **LaggedCreatedDate**. LaggedCreatedDate is computed via the window function

**lag(CreatedDate) over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate) as LaggedCreatedDate**

Here is an image of what Y looks like:

[image: Table Y]

I am trying to write a SQL Query in which I find all rows in X that fall between any LaggedCreatedDate and CreatedDate for a given row in Y for a matching ID.

For example,

Consider row 2 of Y:

**LaggedCreatedDate:** 2020-10-09 21:32:09.872015
**CreatedDate:** 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8876387

If there exists any row in X with ID = 1000000, say Xj such that 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8720156 <= Xj <= 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8876387, I would like that obtain that row of X as a part of the output of the query.

So for a concrete example, Xj = 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8730156 would suffice.

My apologize if my choice of words was confusing. This was quite difficult for me to articulate.

Any direction is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

--posting as answer because I can't comment as of posting this

this question is not very clear but I assume that you are filtering row on basis of single column.

If this is the case then you query should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM joined
WHERE 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8720156 <= Xj AND  Xj <= 2020-10-09 21:32:09.8876387
```